# Ubuntu 10.04 - Issue LAPACK/BLAS API. A required library with BLAS API not found

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-10.04, lapack, blas

I am trying to install `jrl-mathtools` in my machine.

The operative system is **Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS 32-bit**.

The version of **LAPACK is 3.2.1**

The version of **BLAS is 1.2**

Basically, during the installation the terminal shows the following message:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:457 (message):
  A required library with BLAS API not found.  Please specify library
  location.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:139 (find_package)
  cmake/lapack.cmake:29 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (SEARCH_FOR_LAPACK)
```

All the packages theoretically are installed.
Then, I really don't have idea about how to solve the problem.

Someone can help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have de devel packages installed.

- libblas-doc
- libblas-dev
- liblapack-doc
- liblapack-dev

Answer (score 0):

All the packages are already installed.

Moreover, I updated cmake with the last version.

An other idea? 
Thanks anyway